# GCP KMS : Encryption taking place but decryption isn't

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, cryptography, google-cloud-kms

I'm working on a project where encryption and decryption is going to be done using GCP KMS. As a part of the POC, I'm trying to create a function which encrypts and decrypts a string using KMS. While I believe encryption is happening properly, the decryption isn't happening as expected. Here is my code :

```
  public String encryptAndDecrypt() throws IOException {

    try (KeyManagementServiceClient client = KeyManagementServiceClient.create()) {

      String plaintext = "Just an ordinary string";
      CryptoKeyName keyVersionName = CryptoKeyName.of("us-con-gcp-npr-0000305-041421",
              "global", "test", "test1");

      // Encrypt the plaintext.
      EncryptResponse response = client.encrypt(keyVersionName, ByteString.copyFromUtf8(plaintext));
      String cipherText = response.getCiphertext().toStringUtf8();
      System.out.printf("Ciphertext: %s%n", cipherText);
      // Decrypt the ciphertext
      DecryptResponse decryptResponse = client.decrypt(keyVersionName, ByteString.copyFrom(cipherText.getBytes()));
      System.out.printf("Plaintext: %s%n", decryptResponse.getPlaintext().toStringUtf8());
    }
    return "Done";
  }
```

I actually got this code from GCP documents. However, I keepgetting this error :

```
 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Decryption failed: the ciphertext is invalid.
```

Please help

Comment: `EncryptResponse().getCiphertext()` returns a `ByteString`. `ByteString#toStringUtf8()` performs a UTF-8 decoding. Since ciphertexts are generally not UTF-8 conform, this leads to a corruption of the data. For a conversion into a string a binary-to-text encoding like Base64 should be used instead of the UTF-8 decoding.

Answer (score 1):

The ciphertext is a byte array and not a UTF8 encoded string. Your code is corrupting the ciphertext.

Change:

```
String cipherText = response.getCiphertext().toStringUtf8();
```

To:

```
byte[] cipherText = response.Ciphertext.ToByteArray();
```